# Using laravel mix for production

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack, frontend

What are  the best practices of compiling files? Should i make 1 compiled js file with a lot of unused libraries on different pages? Or should i manually compile different files for different pages?

Comment: If you can use `http2` multiple files would be better, because of the async loading. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/script-loading-between-http1-1-and-http2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is you can organize your JS and CSS into categories like this

- frameworks.js - includes Jquery, Bootstrap JS etc
- application.js - specific to your application

You can do the same thing with the css files

- framework.css
- application.css

I would take all of your application JS files like login.js, validation.js etc and compile those into **application.js**
Same idea with the css files.

All of your dependencies will be in one file and application specifc JS into your main **application.js** file